# Imagemagick crop loop not working well

Tags: bash, imagemagick, crop, imagemagick-convert

I need to cut 16 images out from one. 
All images in **`.tif format`**.
Coordinates of top left points of each images contains in text file.
It's like

```
100,200
300,400
...
```

I used this **bash code**

```
IFS=','
while read x y; do 
convert image.tif -crop 262x262+$x+$y image_%02d.tif; 
done < coordinates
```

And it's give me 395 images with wrong coordinates.
I use **`Ubuntu 14.04, Imagemagick 6.7.7`** 
Please any help.

Comment: Where do you open the text file that contains the coordinates? You should first open it and read it line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - you don't have any variable to represent the `%02d` in your output file specifier.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
IFS=','
while read x y; do 
name=$(printf "image%02d.tif" $i)
convert image.tif -crop 262x262+$x+$y "$name"
((i++))
done < coordinates
```

If you don't really need the images to be called `image01.tif` and `image02.tif`, and `image1.tif`, `image2.tif` is ok, you can simply use this

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
IFS=','
while read x y; do 
convert image.tif -crop 262x262+$x+$y image$i.tif
((i++))
done < coordinates
```